# How do I display certain html based on if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a plugin on my wordpress site allows me to create only ONE template for posts when viewed in single item. However, these single items can be different categories, and need different views. 
I have created a view for the Announcements category, but now I want to set a view for the Media category.
I think I can do this by making div classes for Announcements and Media and using Javascript to toggle displays based on something.
Im not sure what exactly that something can be. The only thing that had categories in my source is:

```
 <div class="above-entry-meta"><span class="cat-links"><a 
 href="http://localhost/wordpress2018/category/announcement/" 
 style="background:#fff" rel="category tag">Announcement</a>&nbsp;</span> 
 </div>
```

1. How would I target that on Javascript?
2. What condition in JS should I set?
3. What would I have to place on my HTML.

---

Here is the output that i'm trying to target:

Announcement view:

```
   <announcement>
   the announcement stuff goes here.
   </announcement>
```

Media view:

```
   <media>
   the media stuff goes here.
   </media>
```

I am thinking something along the lines of

```
if (href == "http://localhost/wordpress2018/category/announcement/") {
 $("media").hide();
 };
 }
 else if (href == "http://localhost/wordpress2018/category/media/") {
  $("announcement").hide();
  }
```

I am still a noob at javascript, so thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the full code?

Comment: You say "when viewed in single item", but then you use a category archive Url like `/category/announcement/`. Also, why JS? Those tasks usually happen on the server side when WP is loading template files.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this all wrong !!! Since you want to have different templates for these 2 different categories you actually need 2 different template files! category-announcement.php and category-media.php - this is the WP way. What you're doing is totaly wrong - your media will never use the announcement custom archive template, but it will be loaded in the default archive template, thats why your jquery code will do nothing at all! Check this article - https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates